# Gradle 'TestApp' project refresh failed

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am new to android studio. I have installed android studio 2.1 and imported an eClipse project into it as my first project. After finishing import job, an error occurred with this title:

> Gradle 'TestApp' project refresh failed
>
> ►Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

I notice that in `Tools > Android > SDK manager > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Update Sites` there are errors with `Android Repository` and `Legacy Android Repository`.

> Android Repository https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml
>
> Legacy Android Repository  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-12.xml

I have reinstalled Android studio and then installed and updated all extra fields in SDK manager. I have Android 4.4.2 and 5.0.1 SDK platforms. I Have all tools items installed in SDK manager.

> There are no errors in `Standalone SDK Manager`.

I tried creating a new project. But same error appears.
How can I resolve the issue and run this app?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the Android SDK Manager and at this time I noticed that I got **Android SDK Platform-tools** (upgrade) and **Android SDK Build-tools** (new).

After installing those, I was finally able to fully compile my project.

Note: The latest ADT (Version 23) should be installed.

Comment: I Have all tools items installed in SDK manager. 

Platform tools version is 23.1 and Build tools versions are 17, 18.0.1, 18.1, 19.1, 23.0.3.

The problem should be somewhere else.